# Is it possible to extend an underline of a text in Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, underline, tailwind-3

I want to extend the underline of a tittle text that i have to be a little bit longer than the text itself. I have tried to do this with border bottom but cannot achieve the desiger length for it to not expand through the whole screen.Is it possible to do it with underline?
`

```
 <h1 class="text-5xl font-bold  mt-64 text-center  underline decoration-card-blue underline-offset-30  ">
     About Us      
  </h1>
```

`

I have tried with border bottom but i do not want the whole screen to be underlined just the portion where the wording is and a little bit of extentsion to the side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Welcome</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css'>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="text-5xl font-bold  mt-64 text-center  underline decoration-card-blue underline-offset-30  ">     About Us           </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

use blank character after and before
[codepen example](https://codepen.io/mamun-rashid-raja/pen/gOKxwJV)

Comment: tho this answer works. some formatter plugins may break the code. A better approach should be using a `border-b` class along with horizontal padding. such as `border-b px-6`

Comment: "border-b px-6" added in codepen example but it's not working.

Comment: can you please check this pen https://codepen.io/peshrawahmed/pen/zYadoEJ

Comment: yeah its perfect